# Find the best constant $\|u\|_{L^r}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^a\|u\|_{L^q}^{1-a}$.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Can someone give me a reference for computing the optimal constant $C$ (independent of $u$) in the inequality
$$\|u\|_{L^r(\mathbb R^d)}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^d)}^a\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^d)}^{1-a},$$
where $u\in\mathcal C^1_c(\mathbb R^d)$ radial and $$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{a}{p}+\frac{1-a}{q}$$
with $p,q\geq 1$ and $a\in [0,1]$ and $d\geq 1$.

Comment: This is a case of [Gagliardo-Nirenberg's interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo–Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality). In this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782402012667), see Theorem 1, the optimal constant is computed in the case 
$$\|u\|_{2p} \leq C \|Du\|_{2}^a \|u\|_{p+1}^{1-a}.$$
Maybe you get some ideas from this proof.

Comment: @MarvinF: Thanks for the reference, but in a first time I would like to find easier cases (for example in $d=1$).